# How to detect on waiting for user input from bash script?

Tags: bash, node.js

My bash script looks like:

```
read -p "Do you wish to continue?" yn
# further actions ...
```

And I just want to interact with this script using nodejs / child_process. 
How can I detect that it's waiting for the user input?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var proc = spawn('./script.sh');
proc.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("Data from bash");
}
proc.stdin.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("Data from bash"); // doesn't work :/
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: So you don't see the "Do you wish to continue?"

Comment: Right, I don't see this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ```
> read -p prompt
> ```
>
> Display prompt on **standard error**, without a trailing newline, before
>   attempting to read any input. The prompt is displayed **only if input is
>   coming from a terminal**.

And I don't think there a any way in node.js to detect that the script is *waiting* for input. The problems is actually that bash detects a non-terminal and disables the output to standard error. And even then you would have to read from stderr and not stdin to detect any *waiting states*.

In the end, as Antoine pointed out, you might have to use tools like [empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) or [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to wrap your shell-scripts and trick Bash to think it is in a terminal.

Btw.: `proc.stdin.write("yes\n")` works fine. Thus you could work with the script, but won't get any prompts on `proc.stderr` and will not know *when* the script actually reads the input. You can also immediately `proc.stdin.write` the input even if the script is not yet at the `read -p` statement. The input is buffered until the scripts eats it up.

Comment: Thank you! I've skipped this notice somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use "expect" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect ?
It's a tool that "expect" some text (it use regular expression) and the bash script can automatically answers.